# I can't include an ejs partial in my pages and I'm not sure why

Tags: node.js, ejs

So I'm having some trouble with my ejs templates. Below is how my file structure. In the file `pages/index.ejs`, I am importing the partials `partials/ga.ejs`. It works wonderfully. However, if I added the same partials code into another page.. such as `pages/blog.ejs`, it doesn't work anymore.

It's like I can't import a partial in more than once.

Below is the file structure:

[image]

EDIT; sorry, I forgot to include how I'm including it. So in the `pages/index.ejs` file:

`<% if (showGoogleAnalytics) { %>
    <% include ../partials/ga %>
    <% } %>`

Comment: Could it be the path is relative to the ejs file? You could try `../partials/ga.ejs`. Do you get any error?

Comment: @RolandStarke sorry, updated the code. but yeah, I add that and it spits out an error when I run my express server.